# Stuck on implementation of WebBrowser Control and working with AJAX responses

Tags: c#, ajax, browser

Here we go...

I am trying to create a bot to walk through various functions of a website I do not have control of. Initially, I thought it would be best to just connect to the database (MySql) that the site is tied to and make my associations there...The database is built so extensively that I can't make out where to point what to where how etc...It's beyond my (DBA)programmer casting...  ;)
So, my next idea was, create a bot...simple enough right? First hurdle, not everything on the page carries an ID...bring on the loops...

Got it.

Now I'm stuck with working with my data and page response.

I'm trying to fill out part of a form and perform an AJAX search. The problem is, there is no DocumentCompleted for this. And honestly, that isn't where my problem lies. I've tried using Thread.Sleep, Timers, etc...no avail.

```
// The app reads categories from a csv file, 
// then performs a search for the category
// Search results are only displayed if I break the foreach loop
foreach (var item in bar)
{
var document = wbBrowser.Document;
if (document != null)
{
    var name = document.GetElementById("product_filter_name");
    if (name != null)
    {
        name.SetAttribute("value", item.Key.ToString());

        var buttons = document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (HtmlElement button in buttons)
        {
            var findSearch = button.InnerHtml.IndexOf("Search");

            if (findSearch > -1)
            {
                button.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }

    // This where the problem starts...
    // I want the AJAX to run, then perform Step two,  
    // but the WebBrowser doesn't return the search 
    // results until the end (break;)
    // Step Two

    var elems = document.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
    {
        // find particular item in result table
    }

    break;

    // Now the search results display!!!!
    // I tried implementing a timer, Thread.Sleep,
    // everything I could find via Google before 
    //starting Step Two, but it hasn't worked!
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The actual browser control has a `WebBrowser.OnDocumentCompleted` event which you might need to hook into so that you can be alerted when the ajax call has returned back from the server.

Comment: This doesn't always fire correctly on ajax requests, depending on which frame the are in. It can also fire multiple times, when the result element hasn't been rendered yet.

Comment: First - the browser control is not multi-threaded (it won't process ajax requests simultaneously) altough it is thread friendly as far as Widnows Forms are concerned. 2nd the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` holds a URL property. If you have multi-frames, it is enough to compare each document's (and that is `HtmlDocument`) URL property to the URL property of the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` to know which frame finished loading.

Comment: I have actually tried hooking into the WebBrowser.OnDocumentCompleted event, but that wasn't where the issue lies. I believe the initial Thread that the webbrowser control is sitting in is hanging during my foreach loop and no matter how I wait for that thread to complete, it doesn't show a result until I break the loop. I even tried implementing a background worker...